# virtualkeyborad hidden Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, hidden, virtual-keyboard

I have a problem , I'm making forum and when I insert a post if I give the EditText to write I get the virutal keyboard and I can not see what you write.

anyone has any idea how to raise the EditText not hidden by the virtual keyboard

this is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.aulasg.Foros" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvForoTemas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="392dp" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comentarioMensaje"
        android:layout_width="281dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.49"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.49"
        android:onClick="insertarComentario"
        android:text="Button" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add this properties android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"  in you Activity tag on AndroidManifest.xml or try to post your AndroidManifest.xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the follow code for your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work :S Can anybody help me plz?

Answer (score 0):

You should put this line: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

in you Activity in the manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Name_of_your_ativity"     
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```